# how to get sound level in db in terms of frequency and amplitude in android

Tags: android, audio

I have created an app where i can Get the sound level in db in terms of frequency and amplitude

```
public double getAmplitude() {

    if (mRecorder != null)
        return (mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()/2700.0);
    else
        return 0;
}

public double getAmplitudeEMA() {
   double amp = getAmplitude();
   measure(4096);
   mEMA = EMA_FILTER * amp + (1.0 - EMA_FILTER) * mEMA;
   return mEMA;
}
```

Thank You

Payal Jain

Comment: I am using this code I want sound level in db

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify. I'm guessing you want to know how to convert raw signal amplitude values to a decibel scale like dBFS, but this has nothing to do with frequency, and it's not Android-specific either.